# Frequently Wifi network disappears on Windows 8

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, laptop, windows-8

I'm using Windows 8. My Laptop is DELL inspiron 5110 15r. The problem is, I'm getting warning sign on the tray wifi network icon very frequently. When I hover mouse on warning sign, baloon with following message appears "No network access, No internet access".  I have few other devices at home, they work well with this same network. What can be issue? 
I'm using win 7 divers for it's wifi card. Maybe it's driver related problem, but I haven't found windows 8 drivers for my laptop. 
[image]

I can give you teamviewer access if anyone can solve this problem. I can't figure out

Comment: These other devices that you mention that do work, are they wireless? They work correctly when they are in the same area your laptop will not? What is your router?

Comment: @Logman `are they wireless?` What a strange question are you asking? Of course they are, question is all about wireless network and laptop. Yes they are in the same area with laptop. Router is TP-Link. Signal strange is always 2 or 3 bars. It receives signals but frequently gives mentioned warning

Comment: then you should state the obvious... because I will ask the obvious first and work my down the list. Thats like I asked for the router info and you give me a brand name. That does not help. You do not say what the other devices are... mobile... laptops? tablets? nobody can help unless you give details. And I always start with the obvious questions when all I have to go with is vague problem.